# Randomly sample rows of data frame with given weights (frequency)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame in the following format: one column with raw sequences, another column with the number of times a sequence occurs, and other columns with other characteristics.

```
c1 <- c(324, 213, 122, 34)
c2 <- c("SDOIHHFOEKN", "SDIUFONBSD", "DSLIHFEIHDFS", "DOOIUDBD")
c3 <- c("G", "T", "U", "T")

df <- data.frame(count = c1, seq = c2, other = c3)
```

My actual data frame has over 10^6 rows and 20 columns.

I want to randomly sample N sequences from this, while maintaining the data frame structure as above. For example, I want to randomly sample 300 sequences from the above data frame. Theoretically, the ratio of the four unique sequences present here should be retained in the final data frame.

How can this random sampling happen? I was thinking of using `reshape::untable` to expand the data frame and then use a random number generator and grep to get the rows, but then I cannot get it back into the initial data frame format with each row having a unique sequence and the count of how many times the sequence shows up.

Thanks!

Comment: `sample` allows for probability, so you could try something like: `sample(c2, 300, replace = TRUE, prob = c1 / sum(c1))`

Comment: @MikeH. How could I get the actual count of each sequence in the final data frame though? This would keep the relative frequencies the same, but doesn't give me an absolute count. Thanks!

Comment: You want to sample the sequences and then count the sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sample.int for speed:

```
sampled_df <- df[sample.int(nrow(df), 300, replace = TRUE, prob = df$count),] %>% 
group_by(seq) %>% 
summarize(count = n(), other=unique(other)) %>% 
as.data.frame

> sampled_df
           seq count other
1     DOOIUDBD    21     T
2 DSLIHFEIHDFS    53     U
3   SDIUFONBSD   102     T
4  SDOIHHFOEKN   124     G
```

Comment: How would this work if I had 18 other columns also which are specific to each sequence? I see here that you had to specifically mention `other` but for 18 other variables, I would prefer not to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I can see two approaches: you can look into dplyr `summarize_at` or `summarize_all` if you want to go heavy into dplyr.  Otherwise, you can just `merge` your new data.frame back with the original, using `seq` as the key.  I would prefer the second approach, since it's just annotation and less complicated.